# Console redirection of the current process in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I am trying to redirect the Console output of a C#/Mono application into a gtk# textview.  There are zillions of answers here explaining how to redirect output of a command to whatever output device conceivable.  However, I am trying to do the same on the current process.  Originally the application was designed as command line, know I want a textview that displays all output.  Here is what I have right now:

```
class Program
{
     Main(string[] args)
     {
           Program prog = new Program();
           Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
           proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput =  true;
           proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
           proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
           proc.ErrorDataReceived += prog.DataReceived;
           proc.OutputDataReceived += prog.DataReceived;
           proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
           proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
     }
     void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
     {
           _MainWindow.SendData(e.Data);
     }
}
```

Is this the right approach?  Right now I am receiving the following exception when calling the `BeginErrorReadLine()` method.  The exception is just :     `Standard Error Can not be redirected`.  I don't know if the problem is just the Process/Mono thing, or If I am just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can't redirect stdout after the process has started (which is the cases for the current process).

Have a look at the [Console.SetOut Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=VS.100).aspx):

> Sets the Out property to the specified TextWriter object.

Example:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

This redirects the output of "Hello World" to the text file.

You'd need to implement your own TextWriter that writes all text to the gtk# textview.

---

Alternatively, since it's your program, you could replace all calls to Console.Write/WriteLine with a custom method that writes the string to the gtk# textview or the console, depending on program argument:

```
abstract class Stdout
{
    public static readonly Stdout Instance = // ...

    public abstract void WriteLine(string s);

    private class Console : Stdout
    {
        public override void WriteLine(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

    private class Gui : Stdout
    {
        public override void WriteLine(string s)
        {
            // append to gtk# textview
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at this before, but I use the writer, then I could only get the Console messages in bulk, right?  What I need is that each message is sent independently to the textview.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in using Vte. Vte is the terminal emulation widget used by gnome-terminal. It has C# bindings included with gnome-sharp.

You can actually tell it to start a process using one method. [Here is the documentation for the Vte.Terminal class](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aVte.Terminal%2f*). Specifically, look at the [ForkCommand()](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=M%3aVte.Terminal.ForkCommand%28System.String%2cSystem.String[]%2cSystem.String[]%2cSystem.String%2cSystem.Boolean%2cSystem.Boolean%2cSystem.Boolean%29) method.